# im trying to make a dynamic route on nextjs13.4 and im a doing it right?

Tags: typescript, rest, next.js

I'm not seeing the list I made under localhost3000/blog/loremIpsum

these are the posts I made under the app directory `/app/api/content/route.ts`

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const posts = [
    {
        title:"nfcefce",
        slug:"ejcerc-334",
        content:"just and excer"
    },
    {
        title:"ej3e",
        slug:"ejcerc-334",
        content:"just a34j3oi"
    },
    {
        title:"opo909203",
        slug:"ejcerc-334",
        content:"just a23i939834"
    },
];



export async function GET() {
    return NextResponse.json(posts)
}
```

this is the `app/blog/[slug]`

```
export const revalidate = 420

interface Post{
    title:string,
    content:string,
    slug:string,
}

interface Props{
    params:{slug:string}
}
export default async function page({params}:Props) {

    const posts:Post[] = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/content').then(
        (res) => res.json()
    )
    const post = posts.find((post)=> post.slug === params.slug)!;


  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{post?.title}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm basically not seeing any of the post.

I'm trying to fetch the post and then show it on localhost3000/blog/lorenIpsum

Comment: Is that the exact route you're opening in the browser? It doesn't look like a post exists with the slug lorenIpsum. Your component is trying to show a specific post, not a list.